# MIPS - Runtime exception at 0x00400160: address out of range 0x00000000 Invalid language element

Tags: mips

I'm trying to write a code which calculate cumulative sume of three digits in arrayA, and save the result into an arrayB and then prints them, only the cumulative section occur error.

It occurs Runtime exception at 0x00400160: address out of range 0x00000000 Invalid language element in line 'sll $t6, $t2, 2' in Next section

```
Next:
    sll $t6, $t2, 2      # $t6 = t2(b_idx) \* 4
    lw $t7, 0($t6)       # $t7 = B\[b_idx\]  
    sw $t0, 0($t6)       # B\[b_idx\] = tmp_sum
    li $t0, 0            #tmp_sum = 0
    addi $t2, $t2, 1     #b_idx++
    blt $t1, $a0, Loop   # Loop until i \< B_SIZE
    jr $ra
```

Comment: There is no way that an `sll` instruction causes any kind of memory access violation. So, it has to be an `lw` or `sw` that is faulting.,  In any case, what it is telling you is that you are dereferencing the null pointer value, which is a bad thing.  Find out who provided the null pointer value, and fix that.  The sequence for an array reference with integer elements should be shift, add, load/store.  You have shift, load, which doesn't work, so maybe it is the add you're missing.

Comment: I'm guessing at some point you've shifted all the bits out of `$t6` resulting in you trying to load from memory address 0 (null pointer dereference). What is the value of `$t2` just before the loop begins?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to index your array, it appears as though you are forgetting to add the offset to the base address of the array. In your example $t2 is your loop variable (which I will call "i"). In order to get the value at array[i], you must not only get the offset of i, but also *add* that offset to the base address of the array. You are trying to dereference something incorrectly which is why you are getting that error.

If we assume the base address of your array is at $a1, you must include an instruction similar to `add $t6, $t6, $a1` after you sll by 2 to actually get the address that you want to dereference (i.e. array[i]). It appears that there is a large chunk of instructions that I cannot see, but hopefully this helps to solve the current error that you are experiencing. Let me know if you need any further help.